# Change class of select while using validate

Tags: jquery, css, forms, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am using [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com) with [Bootstrap-Select](https://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/) and [Jquery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/). The basic is working but I am trying to change the style of the select if not validated. It is changing, but the wrong element:

[image]

Should not be the `div` but the `button` only, as I can see.

Example here (click in Filter):

https://jsfiddle.net/33krycLh/

Lines here:

```
highlight: function ( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
    $('.TempX').addClass( "btn-danger" );
    $('.TempX .btn').addClass( "btn-danger" );
},
unhighlight: function ( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
    $('.TempX').removeClass( "btn-danger" );
    $('.TempX .btn').removeClass( "btn-danger" );
}
```

And, by the bellow lines, when the submit is successful, the Filter button should be disabled and change the text to `Wait`:

```
var btn = $(this)
btn.button('loading')
```

So, how can the `btn-danger` be applied just to the button and when clicked in Filter, change the text and disable the button? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by:

```
highlight: function ( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
    $('div.TempX>button').addClass( "btn-danger" );
    $('#Filter').addClass( "btn-danger" );
},
unhighlight: function ( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
    $('div.TempX>button').removeClass( "btn-danger" );
    $('#Filter').removeClass( "btn-danger" );
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fp2rkvLx/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your code actually does it for .TempX as well. Try to take out the responsible lines, like here:

```
highlight: function ( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
    //$('.TempX').addClass( "btn-danger" );
    $('.TempX .btn').addClass( "btn-danger" );
},
unhighlight: function ( element, errorClass, validClass ) {
    //$('.TempX').removeClass( "btn-danger" );
    $('.TempX .btn').removeClass( "btn-danger" );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time. But doing what you are suggesting I lose the class for the `Filter` button and the inside buttons on the select get style too, it should not.

Comment: @Khrys, I do not understand your comment, but I can tell you that I have tried this in your fiddle and the button got the class of danger as you wished in your question. As about what class you lose where I am not sure I understood your point.

Comment: Can you please share the updated fiddle? What I was saying is the `btn-danger` is applied to the `select` and for the `Filter` button. After your answer the class works for the select but the filter stays with the `btn-primary` class. Thanks again

Comment: I see. Then the problem is that you use the same class for logic as for styling. Could you modify your code to have a different class for displaying than for logic? In that case you could toggle the logical .danger class for .TempX and the styling .btn-danger class for the button.